# Counting frequency of objects

Tags: django

I would like to find the frequency of an item's price, for instance sugar.

Sugar will have different prices for example price of an item like sugar: 100,120,100,130,100,140.

How do I do that in my django view?

Below is my model:

```
class Costs(models.Model):
    itemname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    unitcost = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    dateprovided = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    retailer = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Nakumatt')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.itemname
```

Comment: Probably you're looking for aggregation functions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db.models import Count

ok = set(Costs.objects.all().values_list("itemname","unitcost").annotate(freq=Count("itemname","unitcost")))
```

This will fetch all itemnames and unitcosts, add a frequency count of how many times the unique pair of them occurs together, and flatten the list to a set (removing any duplicate entries). `annotate` adds the result of an aggregate function (`Count`) to this list, which returns this structure:

```
[('sugar', 120, 1), ('sugar', 150, 4), ('something_else', 105, 10),]
```

Now you have a list of 3-value tuples of `(itemname,price,frequency)`. Of course, if you filter the queryset for only a particular `itemname` before then, you can still perform this function.

**Alternately, to keep in a queryset**

```
 ok = Costs.objects.all().annotate(frequency=Count("itemname","unitcost"))
```

will add a `.frequency` attribute to each model instance in the queryset `ok` that you can call in your view or template.

PLEASE NOTE: You may have multiple identical sets of  `itemname` and `unitcost` with this particular approach, and due to limitations of the Django ORM you may not be able to parse out each unique combination without converting your queryset to another data type.